# Installing packages in running instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Is it possible to install packages in a running instance without restarting the instance in gcp using rest api. I tried startupscript but it does the job only after a system restart.

Answer (score 1):

You may rerun a startup-script without having to restart the VM instance by following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript#rerunthescript) in the GCP documentation. However, you would have to connect to the VM instance through SSH.

Regarding the REST API, there is no GCE Rest API to install packages inside the VM, however feel free to open a feature request for this on [the Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/access-ui).

Package installations are done through generic Linux commands.

Comment: Restapi refers to the googleapi provided for compute engine.